# Laravel 5.5 use User model to relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use the User model that already in the app folder. but it seem it only extends Authenticatable and can't extend by the model Class i want to use it as a link to the other class, like user has only one employee. what else can i do to recycle the user model that is already extended by Authenticatable?

thanks for the help :)

this is the user model that extends the authenticatable

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
    }
}
```

And this is the employee model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{

 //    protected $table = "positions";

    // public function position()
    // {
    //  return $this->hasMany('App\Position');
    // }

    protected $table = "employees";

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: User model also extends Model, but with some inheritance. You can do everything like other models.

Comment: Just follow 'use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable'.

Comment: @MortezaRajabi so it means that the user class has already inherited the model class ?

Comment: Yes, it already does.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question :)

Answer (score 3):

It already inherited Model class. If you follow `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` you will finally find that it is inherited from a Model class. So, your User model has the same features that your other models have.